# AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, datetime

I want to appoint `datetime.datetime` to a variable but I came across this mistake. How can I fix it?

```
from datetime import datetime

liste = {'latest_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
print(liste['latest_time'])

liste = {'latest_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
```

> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your code, you can change just the import statement to:

```
import datetime
```

Within the `datetime` module is an object also called `datetime`.  Your current code is importing the `datetime` object to the main namespace.  So that object class lives in your main namespace just as if you had written:

```
class datetime(object):
    ...
```

Comment: Fixed my issue with `from datetime import datetime, timezone`

Answer (score 0):

#You can simply try below code..

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

from time import mktime

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

print(yesterday)
```